# Wearing tzitzis to bed?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, sleep, tallit-katan, daytime

I know many frum people wear tzitzis to bed, but a while ago a fellow told me that you should wear the tzitzis that you're going to wear the next day, because of an obligation to wear the same set for 24 hours or something like that. I wonder where it says this (if it does). Also, if you have tzitzis you wear specifically for bed (because they often get tangled or knotted etc.), can you wear these and put on a daytime one in the morning before the bracha?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it is actually preferable to take it off when sleeping as there is a specific bracha that you make when putting them on that you would not be able to make if you hadn't taken them off. Where did he say this chiyuv is from?

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47265

Answer (score 6):

I have never heard of a need to wear the same pair of tzizit for 24 hours. The assumption lends itself to a lot of questions and suffice it to say that the question would be enhanced if you can ask this bachor to provide sources for his statement.

As to your question if you can wear a pair of tzizit specifically for bed and change in the morning before the bracha this is actually preferable:

> [Night Tzitzit](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/536572/jewish/Tzitzit-Time.htm)
>
> .... many are careful to wear tzitzit even during
>   the night, and even while sleeping.
>
> There are several reasons for this practice: a) As mentioned above,
>   according to certain opinions, one can fulfill the mitzvah of tzitzit
>   during the night if wearing a designated day garment. b) If waking up
>   after daylight, one will have fulfilled the mitzvah of tzitzit during
>   the morning hours which have elapsed before his wakening. c) According
>   to kabbalah, tzitzit afford a measure of protection to its wearer even
>   after dark.
>
> **If one wears tzitzit while sleeping, it is preferable to have "night tzitzit."** Otherwise, if one wears the same pair of tzitzit night and
>   day, reciting the blessing on the tzitzit in the morning is
>   problematic, for a new mitzvah is not being performed—it is merely a
>   continuation of the mitzvah from the day beforehand. **However, when
>   putting on a different pair of tzitzit in the morning there is no
>   problem with saying the blessing on the new pair—new mitzvah.**

Comment: Clothing designated for use only at night is not obligated in tzitzit at all. "night tzitzit" is probably the worst idea for this possible.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6030/tztzis-at-night

Comment: eramm, is that a response to me? How does it do so?

Comment: @DoubleAA, if the purpose of separate "night _tzitzis_" is to be able to recite a blessing in the morning, then it's sufficient to change in the morning, that is, to have a set of _tzitzis_ designated for **that** night (as opposed to the next day). But it need not then be designated for night in general: it can be identical to other sets of _tzitzis_, and be worn other days. Then it'd not be a _beged layla_ (I assume; CYLOR).

Comment: @msh210 "it is preferable to have 'night tzitzit'" is a really, really, really strange way of saying: "make sure to change your beged in the morning".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the preferable way to do this is to put on a fresh pair of Tzitzis in the morning, so that the Bracha can be said without question, and then sleep in that same pair the following night, changing it in the morning.

This avoids any problems of the Tzitzis being dedicated to the night time, as well as any issues with saying a Bracha on them in the morning.

I heard this from a Rabbi over 20 years ago.

Menachem Posner's comment at eramm's [link](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/536572/jewish/Tzitzit-Time.htm) seems to say the same thing.

So although I have never heard of some obligation to wear the same pair for 24 hours, it is possible this is where the idea comes from: Wear the same pair at night, as the previous day.

Comment: You could also wear the same pair as the _following_ day, which also "avoids any problems of the Tzitzis being dedicated to the night time, as well as any issues with saying a Bracha on them in the morning."

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't think it is as complete and avoidance of the issues (although le-Halacha you are probably right that the effect would be the same).

Comment: In what way is it an incomplete avoidance of those issues? The only 'negative' aspect of that solution is that for the first 12 hours you haven't said a bracha yet.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I believe there are opinions that you should have.

Answer (score -3):

see arizal who writes one should wear tzitzis even at night, while sleeping.

Comment: -1 I don't see how this addresses the question.

Comment: maybe i'm colour blind! "I wonder where it says this (if it does)"!!

Comment: I don't know what color has to do with it, but the antecedant of "_this_" in your quote is "you should wear the tzitzis that you're going to wear the next day, because of an obligation to wear the same set for 24 hours" as far as I can tell. Does the R Luria address that? If he does, consider editing it into this answer.