# Do I need to wear a different tallit katan when I sleep?

Tags: halacha, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, sleep, tallit-katan

If I wear a tallit katan during the day and also to bed, can I wear the same one during the day and also to bed? Or must the one I wear to bed be a different one than the one I wore during the day?

Also, if this changes anything, I'm Sephardic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wearing tzitzis to bed?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35419/wearing-tzitzis-to-bed)

Comment: Hi NS23, welcome to Mi Yodeah. Your question is a fine question for this site, but it happens to have been asked already, so it will likely get closed as a duplicate. There us nothing wrong with that, and stick around and feel free to ask and answer other questions on the site.

Comment: @Yishai, I don't think this is a duplicate (although very closely related), since it's asking a different question, even if the answers may end up being very similar. I like your welcoming style, BTW.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6030/tztzis-at-night shows that you should not wear it to bed unless you are wearing a "beged yom" in which case you are staying up.

Comment: Does one need to wear a tallit kattan at all?

Answer (score 1):

Per [Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/536572/jewish/Tzitzit-Time.htm) one should wear a different pair at night, in order to be a ble to make a Bracha on the Tzitzis in the morning.

> If one wears tzitzit while sleeping, it is preferable to have "night
>   tzitzit." Otherwise, if one wears the same pair of tzitzit night and
>   day, reciting the blessing on the tzitzit in the morning is
>   problematic, for a new mitzvah is not being performed—it is merely a
>   continuation of the mitzvah from the day beforehand. However, when
>   putting on a different pair of tzitzit in the morning there is no
>   problem with saying the blessing on the new pair—new mitzvah.

Comment: That's odd. Why would they say it's preferable to wear a beged that's exempt from tzitzis?

Comment: @DoubleAA: I reread my answer and I do not understand your comment. Who says that it's preferable to wear a beged that's exempt from tzitzis?

Comment: Your quote does. Note any four cornered garment which is both a) being worn at night, and b) designated for wearing only at night, is exempt from tzitzis. OC 18:1.

Comment: @DoubleAA: I give up

Comment: ??? There's nothing to give up? It's not _your_ fault. You are just quoting.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to wear a tallit katan while sleeping. The mitzvah only applies during the day. This is what is refer to as a Mitzva Aseh SheHazman Grama (positive time bound commandment) On the other hand there are those who still wear there tzitzis at night time either all of the time or at least when sleeping in a place without a mezzuzah.

If one chooses to wear their tallis katan at night time it is important to differentiate between the one worn at night (which isn't obligatory) and the one worn during the day by having a separate tallis katan only worn at night time or at least a different on than the one you will wear during that day

Comment: Or is it Ksus Yom?

Comment: Do you have a source for this claim or is it your own conjecture?

Comment: Partially correct. One opinion says that any 4 cornered beged needs tzitzis, but only by day. The other opinion says that only a beged worn by day needs tzitzis, at any time, day or night. The first opinion is the generally accepted halachah, that you don't need tzitzis by night, however, we're machmir to davka use a day time beged by day. Many people wear tzitzis by night, whether it's to be wearing tzitzis when you wake up, or to keep both opinions. However, the best thing to do would be to change each morning and wear it for 24 hours, that way you're always wearing a ksus yom