# Tzitzit at night but not about the clothing

Tags: halacha-theory, tzitzis, evening-night

There are a variety of questions about wearing [tzitzit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6030/tztzis-at-night) at night (and many [websites](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1SQJL_enUS855US855&sxsrf=ALeKk00aq-Z-cpfrBImpQp5NXNTcROqghw%3A1604866507360&ei=y1GoX_etFZGxggeQj7awAQ&q=tzitzis%20night&oq=tzitzis%20night&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIJCAAQyQMQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46BAgjECc6BAgAEEM6BQgAEJECOggILhCxAxCDAToLCC4QsQMQxwEQowI6CggAELEDEMkDEEM6BQguELEDOgIIADoCCC46CAguEMcBEK8BOgcIABAUEIcCOgUIABCxAzoHCAAQsQMQQzoHCCMQsQIQJzoECAAQCjoKCAAQyQMQFBCHAjoECAAQHlDVkgFY6KUBYN-mAWgAcAB4AIAB4AGIAeQLkgEFNi42LjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi3v9TQ4fPsAhWRmOAKHZCHDRYQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) discussing the laws) But they seem to focus on the source, "ur'eetem" as relating to the clothes that you might wear to sleep.

Is there a source that discusses either [3rd](https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/finding-a-job/third-shift-schedule) shift workers who would not be going to sleep (and very likely, are in lit offices in which they can see things) or places in which it is not always [dark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_sun) at night? In the former case, the question is about the individual and the question of sleeping, and the second, more on the geography invalidating the concern about seeing things outside.

Comment: It's a machloqes between the Rambam and the Rosh whether tzitzis is limited to daytime (Rambam), or to clothing usually worn during the day, regardless of when it is actually being worn (Rosh). The Arukh haShulchan discusses it at OC 18:1-7.  He concludes we have to be strict in both directions -- requiring tzitzis on day clothes worn at night, and on pajamas worn during the day (if you had poncho-shaped pajamas).