# Tzitzit and women

Tags: halacha, women, tzitzis, orach-chaim, time-bound

According to Halacha, women are exempt from being obligated to perform positive, time bound, commandments. My question is, since Tzitzit aren’t time bound but only required if one is going to wear a four cornered garment, why are women Petur from them? It seems different from tefillin which are supposed to be worn daily especially since it’s at least technically optional.

Is there a reason this is considered similar to time bound mitvzot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tztzis at night](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6030/tztzis-at-night)

Comment: "According to Halacha, women are exempt from being obligated to perform positive, time bound, commandments." Note this "rule" probably has more exceptions than actual applications. Some major rishonim understood it as a mere mnemonic, not a reason to exempt women but a way to note which commands women happen to be exempt from for various specific local reasons.

Comment: Tzitzis is a time-bound mitzva, even according to the [Rosh](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_on_Menachot%2C_Hilchot_Tzitzit.1.1?lang=bi#:~:text=%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A4%22%D7%94%20%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%90).

Comment: @DoubleAA interestingly, I heard R’ Aryeh Lebowitz in a shiur (quoting I believe one of the Roshei Yeshiva at RIETS) that the total # of mitzvot under that category are likely somewhere between 5-7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The halakhah accords with R. Shim'on. See Menahoth 43a:

> ת"ר הכל חייבין בציצית כהנים לוים וישראלים גרים נשים ועבדים ר"ש פוטר
> בנשים מפני שמצות עשה שהזמן גרמא הוא וכל מצות עשה שהזמן גרמא נשים
> פטורות... ר"ש פוטר בנשים מאי טעמא דר"ש דתניא (במדבר טו, לט) וראיתם
> אותו פרט לכסות לילה
>
> Our Rabbis taught: All must observe the law of sisith, Kohanim,
> Lewiim, and Yisraelim, converts, women and slaves. R. Shim'on
> declares women exempt, since it is a positive precept dependent on a
> fixed time, and women are exempt from all positive precepts that are
> dependent on a fixed time...R. Shim'on declares women exempt. What is
> R. Shim'on's reason? — It was taught: "That you may look upon it" (Num.
> 15:39) this excludes a night garment.